# HighChart Boost Module in highmaps not working

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-boost

I'm try to add highcharts boost module on my highmap with big data but Its not working. I'm getting error on the console when i add the boost.js cdn in my code

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Does the highcharts boost module support highmaps?
If yes how do i go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Highcharts boost module does not support Highmaps. Check the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module):

> Boost is a stripped-down renderer-in-a-module for Highcharts and
>   Highstock.
>
> The boost module is a “renderer-in-a-module”. Including
>   modules/boost.js will, by default, activate boost for all series that
>   support it (line series, column, bar, treemap, heatmap, scatter,
>   bubble, area).